# Fresh installed laravel 5.6 getting HTTP ERROR 500 in index page

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, backend

Hi everyone I'm having a hard time debugging an issue in laravel 5.6 freshly installed after upgrading from php 7.0 to php 7.1. I've already generated an app key for my test project. Changed owner to www-data and permission to 777 since it's just a test project.

Restarting php 7.1 fpm and NGINX is also done.

Please note that I can be able to run the project after running **php aritsan serve** command, I'm also able to ping the project but not able to access it using **laraveltestauth.ng** in URL.

**laravel.log**

```
[2018-02-27 02:45:28] local.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) at /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(301): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/development/si...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#2 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php(120): spl_autoload_call('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#3 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(420): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Finder->depth(0)
#4 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(381): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->directories('/development/si...')
#5 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1038): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\{closure}(Object(Whoops\\Handler\\PrettyPageHandler))
#6 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(384): tap(Object(Whoops\\Handler\\PrettyPageHandler), Object(Closure))
#7 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(334): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->whoopsHandler()
#8 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1038): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\{closure}(Object(Whoops\\Run))
#9 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(339): tap(Object(Whoops\\Run), Object(Closure))
#10 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(314): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderExceptionWithWhoops(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#11 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(287): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->convertExceptionToResponse(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#12 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(188): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#13 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#14 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(326): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#15 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(124): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->renderException(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#16 /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 {main}
"} 
[2018-02-27 02:45:28] local.ERROR: Exception thrown without a stack frame {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 16): Exception thrown without a stack frame at Unknown:0)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

**NGINX Server Config**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /development/sites/www/laravelAuth/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name laraveltestauth.ng www.laraveltestauth.ng;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**Hosthack**

```
127.0.1.1   laraveltestauth.ng          www.laraveltestauth.ng
```

Let me know if there's anything I can add. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Homestead?

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria no I'm not using homestead, I've manually setup LEMP

Comment: Looks like your PHP upgrade resulted in multiple versions of PHP being installed, and your CLI and Nginx are serving different ones. I'm vague on the details for exactly what to check/change (add your system details and that would help), but I'd hazard that you're running two different PHP-FPMs, or its still pointing to the old version.

Comment: I think you are right @Cryode I've tried to run service php7.1-fpm status command and shows that php7.1 is not active and php7.0 is still active

Comment: I had to disable php7.0 and enable php7.1 and everything works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`php artisan server` runs the CLI version which is correct and the latest 7.1.

Your web server is still running the old PHP version. Make sure it is set up correctly with the latest version. Even if you delete the old version, your server can still keep it running in memory until the issue is resolved.

Try `service php7.0-fpm stop` and `service php7.1-fpm restart` and `service nginx restart`.

Comment: thanks Lance, that's exactly what I've done and now my project is now up and running :)